# Query related to threads in Qt

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt4, timer, wait

I want my application to wait indefinitely until a task gets completed in another thread.

How do I perform this in Qt?

On windows, we use `waitforsingletonobject`, but is there any alternative to this?

Comment: This should probably not be tagged with pthreads, as the question is specific to QThreads.

Answer (score 2):

Waiting for threads to finish certain tasks (thread synchronization) is the job of [the QWaitCondition class](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwaitcondition.html).

Answer (score 0):

Call [wait](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qthread.html#wait) on your `QThread` object.

Comment: Since he was referring to "a task" getting completed, I don't think he wants to wait for the entire thread to finish.

Comment: if they use `WaitForSingleObject` on Windows, the Qt equivalent would be doing this.

Comment: wait keeps UI hung i guess, but till what extent i have to wait, infinite amount of time i have to..in this case how to do

Comment: without more information it's hard to give any worthy advice. if there's a UI involved, you probably need to use signals/slots. edit your question to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use QtConcurrent::run. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833535/how-to-thread-the-sorting-of-a-qsortfilterproxymodel). Note that the QFutureWatcher API can work in blocking (the `waitForFinished` method) and non-blocking (the `finished` signal) modes.